# Can you get URL for YouTube video from Google Drive?

Tags: youtube, google-drive

I have a simple link to Google Drive and when I open it it opens YouTube video. Can I get direct YouTube URL from it? In other words I need to watch video by directly hitting YouTube and not going to Google Drive.

I tried to right click on video and  I got only these four options:

- Loop
- Troubleshoot playback issue
- Copy debug info
- Stats for nerds

Comment: Google are probably just making use of their already existing player technology. It's not actually playing *with* YouTube, it just looks like YouTube.

Comment: @Moab thanks for the link but I don't own google drive account, they just shared link to Google drive and I don't see anything else.

Comment: @MichaelFrank maybe, I just assumed it was YouTube because there was YouTube icon on bottom right and interface(buttons, looks and feel) also was YouTube's.

Comment: I asked them to send direct YouTube link and they did it, thank you both.

Comment: @Foxy: Who did you ask and how?

Comment: @Turkeyphant I asked my company management to provide direct link instead of link to Google Drive that they gave me before. They are the ones who uploaded the video to YouTube.